# How to avoid poor performance of pandas mean() with datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a pandas (version `0.25.3`) `DataFrame` containing a `datetime64` column. I'd like to calculate the mean of each column.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, n),
    "d": pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=n, freq="1H").tolist()
})
```

Calculating the mean of individual columns is pretty much instantaneous.

```py
df["x"].mean()
## 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop
df["d"].mean()
## 100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop
```

However, when I use the DataFrame's `.mean()` method, it takes a really long time.

```py
%timeit df.mean()
## 1 loop, best of 3: 9.23 s per loop
```

It isn't clear to me where the performance penalty comes from.

What is the best way to avoid the slowdown? Should I convert the `datetime64` column to a different type? Is using the `DataFrame`-level `.mean()` method considered bad form?

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print(pd.__version__)`?. It takes longer than `Series.mean` for me as well, but it's quite fast still: `4.28 s ± 87.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: What output do you see for `df["d"].mean()`? On Pandas 0.24.2, I get `TypeError: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation mean`.

Comment: Seems to be getting stuck in some slow [`lambda` here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py#L601-L603). But honestly this is more buggy than anything to me. On `0.25.0` `df['d'].mean()` will work, but if you try `df['d'].sum()` you get: `TypeError: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation sum`. Clearly if I can take a `mean` I need to be able to take a sum... I think, if you really want to treat them as numbers then stick with POSIX representation

Comment: Nice catch. How did you come up with that, you used a profiler? @ALollz

Comment: @Erfan haha no i wasn't that sophisticated. I just interrupted the kernel and saw where it was stuck a few times. So it might not be totally true, but seems like a culprit. However I have no idea why `DataFrame.mean()` and `Series.mean()` are behaving differently. Kudos to anyone who figures this out.

Comment: I agree, was thinking about posting this as an issue on GH, seeing what others / devs have to say about this.

Comment: Filed it https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31075

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could restrict it to the numeric values:
`df.mean(numeric_only=True)`

Then it runs very fast as well.

Here is the text from the documentation:

> numeric_only : bool, default None
>   Include only float, int, boolean columns. If None, will attempt to use everything, then use only numeric data. Not implemented for Series.

--
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, I would like to calculate the mean for each column (and setting `numeric_only` to `True` means that the datetime column is skipped).

Comment: If you print `df.mean()` you can see, that it skips the datetime column anyway. Output: `x    0.118684     dtype: float64`

Comment: The answer is helpful as a workaround, but it does not really explain Panda's behavior. I cannot see any reason why the result for each column should take <5ms but 10s for the Dataframe. Also the docstring is not clear at all to me. Why is None a default value? It seems to omit non-numeric data anyway, so what is happening if this is set to False or None? Anyway, thanks for the answer! Especially because I found it by googling "numercy_only"... ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [pandas bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31075).

On the current master (so probably with Pandas >= 1.3), the minimal example in the question will be fast also when running `df.mean()`, but the column `d` is not in the result. You still have to do `df["d"].mean()` to get a result. I guess this is done to avoid breaking changes, but I am not sure.

Passing the parameter `numeric_only=True` to `.mean()` or calling `.mean()` on columns and not on the dataframe are good workarounds.

**Note:** Things are not very intuitive, if your Dataframe contains column with a non-numeric data type, such as string, dates etc. Pandas then tries to do a sum (what ever that means for the datatype), then convert it to numbers and divide by the number of rows. For strings this leads to weird results such as `"42" + "42" + "42"` which is `"424242"` and then converted to `424242.` and divided by 3. For non-numeric values this can be pretty slow. If the concatenation of the strings cannot be converted to a number, the result is either omitted for `df.mean()` or an error is raised for Pandas >= 1.3 or if you call `mean()` on the column.